# How can I create report on Stage velocity as per Sales user

Tags: reporting, opportunity, business-logic, opportunity-history

I want to create a report on Stage velocity of opportunity per sales person. Like if a salesperson have 10 Opps in first stage and only 6 forward to second stage then from 6 only 4 forward to third stage, only one go to fourth stage.

So I would like to calculate sales person stage velocity and see in which stage he is losing more opps so we can help him on that stage.

Please advice any logic to get this report and dashboard.

Comment: Hi, I have created report on Opportunity history with "stage change = True" filter and add custom formula in report: 
Opportunity.Count__c:SUM / PARENTGROUPVAL(Opportunity.Count__c:SUM, FROM_OPPORTUNITY_STAGE_NAME, COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY)
But the stage conversion give me wrong calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Historical Trend Reporting](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_historical_setup.htm). [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbvu81mHH6s) Dreamforce video is really helpful.

A limitation though is that you can report only on the last 3 months of changes. If you need up to 6 months, you can use [Analytics Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_setting_up_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US) but this is quite limited in that it can only accompany up to 2k rows of data. In contract, Historical Trending can be used for up to 5million rows.

Historical trending can be either used for Tabular or Matrix reports. The matrix reports can be used to construct Dashboards.

[image]

[image]

You may find these two links on pipeline velocity also helpful. [Here](http://www.johnwestenhaver.com/2015/04/measuring-pipeline-velocity-in.html) and [here](http://garysmithpartnership.com/sales-velocity-salesforce/).

Comment: also -- you can work around the Analytic Snapshot limit of 2000 per snapshot run by scheduling multiple snapshots to write into the same custom snapshot object (e.g., one snapshot run for AMER, one for EMEA, one for APAC). Also, you can snapshot summary data only rather than raw oppos (counts by salesrep by stage)